# Finding length of curve $y^2 = 64(x+3)^3$ for $0 \le x \le 3$

Tags: calculus, integration, algebraic-curves

[image]

Not getting the right answer for this, can someone point me to where I'm going wrong?

Comment: $1+144(x+3)=1+144x+432=144x+433$, not $144x+37$.

Comment: It seems that you say that $1+144(x+3)=1+144x+36$ which is not correct.

Comment: Oh ok forgot to switch that part when I fixed another mistake. Thanks for saving me from my late night mistake guys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You derived $f'$ directly, but I suggest a different method. $(y^2)'=2yy'$, so $2yy'=64\cdot 3(x+3)^2$. Then
\begin{align}
(y')^2 &= \left(\frac{64\cdot 3(x+3)^2}{2y}\right)^2\\
&=\frac{64^2 3^2 (x+3)^4}{4y^2}\\
&=\frac{64^2 3^2 (x+3)^4}{4\cdot 64(x+3)^3}\\
&=144(x+3).
\end{align}
Therefore $1+(f'(x))^2 =144x+433$. Of course, what you did is almost correct, except a mistake in calculation.